# You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. + $submitButton.click()

Tags: powershell

I'm running a script that I've used for some time successfully, but I am now getting the following error message:

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At
> G:\Backup\2021\DownloadASX300 v1.ps1:14 char:1
> $submitButton.click()
>
> CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

The script I'm running is as follows:

```
$OutputFilePath = "c:\_Temp\ASX300html.htm
$url = 'https://www.marketindex.com.au/asx300'
$IE = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$IE.Navigate($url)
$IE.Visible = $true

while ($IE.Busy -eq $true){Start-Sleep -seconds 5;}

$submitButton=$IE.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getelementsbytagname("a") | Where-Object {$_.innerhtml -like '*SHOW ALL COMPANIES*'}


$submitButton -eq $null
$submitButton.click()

Start-Sleep -s 5

$IE.Document.body.innerHTML | Out-File -FilePath $OutputFilePath
$IE.Quit()
```

This script basically downloads share prices from a website after opening the full list on that site.
Any help you can offer will be greatly apprreciated.

Comment: I'd suspect the url you're scanning has changed the name of the element you're looking for or removed it.

Comment: Hi Scepticalist, thank you for your comment. I've checked the url which is https://www.marketindex.com.au/asx300 and the element is still the same as far as I can see; i.e. Show All Companies.

Comment: Could it be that I was using an earlier version of Internet Explorer and that the latest version, i.e. Internet Explorer 11, is not compatible with this script?

Comment: After running your script with that url, the `$submitButton` variable is emnpty even before you set it to $null (I commented that line out). It's not finding the element you require.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide me with more feedback. If I may ask; do you have any suggestions on how I can amend the script to open the full list of companies on the website before writing their values to a file? The element that the script used to find was the Show All Companies click through button. This button still appears lower down on the website but the script doesn't seem to find this element as you point out.

Comment: If you use a browser like chrome to look at the page source you should be able to find the new element name and amend your script accordingly.